# (HTML + Javascript) Getting text input to display on canvas and radio button input to fill background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the user input change the appear of my canvas with a javascript function. I have run into two problems that I can't seem to fix. 1) my document.getElementById("name") isn't showing on the canvas and it is making the select statement disappear as well. 2) I am trying to get an if loop to change the background color of the canvas to either red or blue. However I do not know how to do it myself. Sorry for such a wordy question. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Greeting Card Generator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var bt = document.querySelector("#draw");
        function draw() {
            var c = document.getElementById("card");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
            ctx.lineWidth = 10;
            ctx.strokeRect(125, 25, 960, 540);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.textAlign = "start";
            ctx.font = "22px Arial";
            ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("name", 435, 55));
            ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("greet").options[document.getElementById("greet").selectedIndex].text, 535, 95);


            var redButton = document.getElementById("bgRed");
            var blueButton = document.getElementById("bgBlue");

            if (redButton.checked) {
                //fill background red
            } else if (blueButton.checked) {
                //fill background blue
            }

            document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        //bt.addEventListener("click",draw);       
    </script>
    <style>
        #div1{
            background-color: cyan;
            font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 25px solid red;
            padding: 25px;
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #div2{
            background-color: cyan;
            font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 25px solid orange;
            padding: 25px;
            width: 50%;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;

        }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">Greeting Card Generator</div>
    <div id="div2">
        What Kind of Greeting Would You Like?<select name="greet" id="greet">
            <option value="-1" selected>-Select-</option>
            <option value="1">Birthday</option>
            <option value="2">Graduation</option>
            <option value="3">Engagement</option>
        </select> 
        <br>
        What is the name of the recipient<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
        <br>
        What background colour would you like on the card?
        <input type="radio" name="background" id="bgRed" value="red" checked/>Red 
        <input type="radio" name="background" id="bgBlue" value="blue" />Blue 
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="make card" id="draw" onclick="draw();">  
    </div>    
    <canvas id="card" width="1400" height="900"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is this line:

```
ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("name", 435, 55));
```

The getElementById is closed too late. Change to:

```
ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("name").value, 435, 55);
```

Snippet:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var bt = document.querySelector("#draw");
  function draw() {
    var c = document.getElementById("card");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    
    // set first the background color
    if (document.getElementById("bgRed").checked) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    }
    ctx.fillRect(125, 25, 960, 540);

    // continue....
    ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.strokeRect(125, 25, 960, 540);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.textAlign = "start";
    ctx.font = "22px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("name").value, 435, 55);
    ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("greet").options[document.getElementById("greet").selectedIndex].text, 535, 95);



    document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
  }
  bt.addEventListener("click",draw);
}
```

```css
#div1{
  background-color: cyan;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 25px solid red;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#div2{
  background-color: cyan;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 25px solid orange;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Greeting Card Generator</div>
<div id="div2">
    What Kind of Greeting Would You Like?<select name="greet" id="greet">
    <option value="-1" selected>-Select-</option>
    <option value="1">Birthday</option>
    <option value="2">Graduation</option>
    <option value="3">Engagement</option>
</select>
    <br>
    What is the name of the recipient<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
    <br>
    What background colour would you like on the card?
    <input type="radio" name="background" id="bgRed" value="red" checked/>Red
    <input type="radio" name="background" id="bgBlue" value="blue" />Blue
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="make card" id="draw">
</div>
<canvas id="card" width="1400" height="900"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract text from a textbox use .value instead. This should work:

```
ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("name").value, 435, 55);
```

If you change that your document should display the name correctly:
[example with changed line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts0zw.png)

Here's the complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Greeting Card Generator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var bt = document.querySelector("#draw");
        function draw() {
            var c = document.getElementById("card");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
            ctx.lineWidth = 10;
            ctx.strokeRect(125, 25, 960, 540);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.textAlign = "start";
            ctx.font = "22px Arial";
            ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("name").value, 435, 55);
            ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("greet").options[document.getElementById("greet").selectedIndex].text, 535, 95);


            var redButton = document.getElementById("bgRed");
            var blueButton = document.getElementById("bgBlue");

            if (redButton.checked) {
                //fill background red
            } else if (blueButton.checked) {
                //fill background blue
            }

            document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        //bt.addEventListener("click",draw);       
    </script>
    <style>
        #div1{
            background-color: cyan;
            font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 25px solid red;
            padding: 25px;
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #div2{
            background-color: cyan;
            font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 25px solid orange;
            padding: 25px;
            width: 50%;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;

        }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">Greeting Card Generator</div>
    <div id="div2">
        What Kind of Greeting Would You Like?<select name="greet" id="greet">
            <option value="-1" selected>-Select-</option>
            <option value="1">Birthday</option>
            <option value="2">Graduation</option>
            <option value="3">Engagement</option>
        </select> 
        <br>
        What is the name of the recipient<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
        <br>
        What background colour would you like on the card?
        <input type="radio" name="background" id="bgRed" value="red" checked/>Red 
        <input type="radio" name="background" id="bgBlue" value="blue" />Blue 
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="make card" id="draw" onclick="draw();">  
    </div>    
    <canvas id="card" width="1400" height="900"></canvas>
</body>
```